# Leverage browser caching - external images

Tags: html, caching, iis-7.5, pagespeed

I've been able to correctly (I think) enable caching on IIS. The only problem now is that when I run Google's PageSpeed Insights it still says

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

But all of the suggestions are external images. I am using Amazon's S3 to externally host images (linking to direct URLs, as

> < img src="http://s3.amazon.com......."/>.

Is there a way I can "leverage browser caching" for these external images?

Thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: you should provide what you have achieved till now so we can give the correct suggestions.

Comment: Apologies if I didn't seem specific enough... it was more that what I had done already made it so all the images locally cached perfectly, but those elsewhere didn't. Someone below pointed out the obvious point I had missed where I cannot control the cache of another site, so I had to do it within S3 itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with Amazon S3 you can still set the `Expires` header of the objects stored in the bucket.

You will have to set this header when storing the object so there are two ways:

- programatically using the API (set the Expiry header with your PUT request)
- in the bucket browser that you use to upload the objects

If you use the API you can do something like

```
PUT /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Authorization: authorization-string
Expires: expiry-date
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

For the second case maybe this link will help: http://www.newvem.com/how-to-add-caching-headers-to-your-objects-using-amazon-s3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it sounds stupid, but I hadn't thought that I'd have to cache it on the S3 server. Sounds really obvious now!!

Answer (score 2):

For single images on S3, you can right click on the image in the bucket, go to properties and choose Metadata.

```
add Key: Cache-Control  and Value: max-age=604800 (this is for 7 days)
```

This works for me. But if you want to edit them in bulk, I guess you have to try command line. If you do from command line, from my understanding you need to copy the images again to enable the maximum age change to work on the images.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0    
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault A3024000
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
```

in your .htaccess file, hope this helps.

Comment: The author of the question stated that they're using IIS which uses primarily Web.config file for configuration and probably not .htaccess file (unless using something like Helicon Ape).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as Tom said, this project is in the Microsoft world.